# Negative Binomial Distribution: impossible probabilities?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, negative-binomial

From what I understand, negative binomial is $P(X=k$ number of trials until $r^{th}$ success)

From this chart,

[image]

For the red graph $r = 10$, $P(X=k$ number of trials until $10^{th}$ success)

For all $X<10$, the probability should be $0$ because it is impossible to have less than $10$ trials and get $10$ successes, but the red graph says that there is a chance. Why?

Comment: Negative binomial models the number of successes before a specified number of failures is achieved.

Comment: There are four ways of specifying the negative binomial: number of trials/failures/successes until $r$th success/failure

Answer (score 1):

Usually negative binomial is defined in terms of number of failures until the $r$ successes have been achieved, not the total number of trials.